# SQL queries getting records from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, posts

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, posts.dislikes, users.`userName`
FROM users,posts,interests
WHERE (posts.user_id =3
OR interests.follower_id =3 AND posts.topics IN(SELECT interest_id FROM interests WHERE follower_id = 3))
AND users.ID = posts.user_id 
AND posts.topics = interests.interest_id
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC
```

This query works fine when user_id =3 is the only person following a certain topic in the interest table. The interest table include id, follower_id, and (interest_id which are topics such as sports).

The posts table include a column for topics which are topics users can follow and once you follow a topic i insert it in the interests table. Now I am trying to retrieve posts made by users, the posts I want to get can either be posts made by me (there is a column in posts called user_id which is the id of the user who posted it) or posts of topics I am following.

The problem here is when i run this query i get duplicate posts because some other user is following the same topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't querying any fields from `interests`, it probably shouldn't be in the join. Converting its usage to an `in` or `exists` condition will eliminate your duplicates. Additionally, you should note that implicit joins (i.e., listing several tables in the `from` clause) are considered to be a bad practice, and you should probably use an explicit join instead:

```
SELECT   posts.id, posts.body, posts.posted_at, posts.likes, posts.dislikes,
         users.userName
FROM     posts 
JOIN     users ON users.id = posts.user_id 
WHERE    posts.user_id = 3 OR 
         posts.topics IN (SELECT interest_id 
                          FROM   interests 
                          WHERE follower_id = 3)
ORDER BY posts.posted_at DESC
```